# Change of variables integration for all real p>1?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, complex-integration

Originally I have the following problem to show it holds for any real $p>1$, 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^p+1}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{p}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{p}\right).$$ However, since there are infinitely many $p$ that fit this kind of form, I was thinking of approaching it in another way. Specifically change of variables integration. I'm embarrassed to admit that I do not know how to proceed.

Thinking: $c_\alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x+1} \, \mathrm{d}x$ where $c$ is a constant and we have a single pole at $z=1$.. I do not trust my change of variables. I may not know how to do this...

Any direction on change of variables integration is appreciated. I know after that I would discuss removable singularities and proceed with Residue Theorem and thus ultimately solving my problem.

Comment: May I suppose that the rhs could be $\frac{\pi }{p} \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)$ instead ?

Comment: By setting $n=0,$ this is a special case of [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx)

Comment: I don't trust how to do the change of variables that you are suggesting Brevan?